# Does \newenvironment have a \provideenvironment cousin, as \newcommand has \providecommand?

Tags: macros, environments

To avoid the problem of having to decide whether to use `\newcommand` or `\renewcommand`, LaTeX has the option of `\providecommand`.

Is there something corresponding to this for environments? I'd like to be able to type `\provideenvironment` (or similar) rather than first using `\newenvironment` and then using `\renewenvironment`.

Comment: Good question!  I think that anyone writing a generic `newX` macro ought to also provide both `renewX` and `provideX` variants.  (I got so fed up of journals defining all different types of theorem variants - and therefore messing up my own definitions - that I wrote a `\providetheorem` command.)

Comment: It's worth pointing out that `\providecommand` isn't to avoid having to decide which to use, it's to provide a definition if one does not already exist. If it does, then `\providecommand` does not redefine it.

Comment: Yes, I think that's probably a better description of its intended usage. But because I often generate LaTeX automatically it's quite convenient for me to use `\providecommand` rather than keep track of whether my LaTeX code has already defined a command (hence the weird way I described its purpose).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I don't believe there is a `\provideenvironment` defined anywhere, but you can define it.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\def\provideenvironment{\@star@or@long\provide@environment}
\def\provide@environment#1{%
        \@ifundefined{#1}%
                {\def\reserved@a{\newenvironment{#1}}}%
                {\def\reserved@a{\renewenvironment{dummy@environ}}}%
        \reserved@a
}
\def\dummy@environ{}
\makeatother

\provideenvironment{foo}[1][blarg]{begin foo: #1 }{end foo}
\provideenvironment{foo}{asdf}{asdf}
\begin{document}
\begin{foo}
whee
\end{foo}
\end{document}
```

The first time `foo` gets defined. The second time it does not because it is already defined.

Comment: Like! Can you tell us/point us to what `\@star@or@long` is and does? It appears very mystical ...

Comment: @user1129682: `\@star@or@long` is defined in the latex kernel (`ltdefns.dtx`): "Look ahead for a `*`. If present reset `l@ngrel@x` so that the next definition, `#1`,  will be non-long".

Answer (score 13):

No.

If you are familiar with `expl3` (but not necessary), you can use `\ProvideDocumentEnvironment` in `xparse` package. The syntax is a little different. For example:

```
\usepackage{xparse}
\ProvideDocumentEnvironment{foo}{ o m }{%
  \IfNoValueTF{#1}{only #2}{#1 and #2}%
}{%
  \IfNoValueTF{#1}{only #2}{#1 and #2}%
}
```

Answer (score 5):

There is a `\provideenvironment` in the package [`makecmds`](http://ctan.org/pkg/makecmds). I suppose that is what you are looking for. Its syntax is analog to that of `\newenvironment`.