# Is there something like \providetikzstyle similar to \providecommand?

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, tikz-styles

I have `standalone` figures that I include in my document. These figures use statements like `\providecommand{\HypotenuseLabel}{$h$}` which allows the figure to have a default label, and which can be over written via `\newcommand{\HypotenuseLabel}{$x^2+y^2$}` in the main file that includes this figure to customise this diagram for that particular application.

This figure also has statements like `\tikzstyle{HypotenuseLineStyle}=[red, very thick, opacity=0.5]` which are used to draw this particular line.  I would like to change this to something of the nature `\providetikzstyle` so that this style only gets defined in the figure if it is not already defined.  Is there an easy way to do this?

[Here is a related question but for environments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20687/does-newenvironment-have-a-provideenvironment-cousin-as-newcommand-has-provi).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

AFAIK `\tikzstyle` was an unofficial, never documented macro. It is used in some code shown in the `pdfmanual` but never described. The correct official syntax is `\tikzset{HypotenuseLineStyle/.style={red, very thick, opacity=0.5}}`.

See section 55.4.4 *Defining Styles*, on page 493. I can't find any `.provide style` or so there, so I don't think there is one. However, it would be possible to define one:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

% .style is defined as \pgfkeys {\pgfkeyscurrentpath /.code=\pgfkeysalso {#1}}
\tikzset{/handlers/.provide style/.code={%
    \pgfkeysifdefined{\pgfkeyscurrentpath/.@cmd}{}%
        {\pgfkeys {\pgfkeyscurrentpath /.code=\pgfkeysalso {#1}}}%
}}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{test/.provide style={green}}% Sets the style

\tikzset{test/.provide style={red}}% Doesn't overwrites the style!

% Do we get the green light?
\tikz \fill [test] (0,0) circle (5pt);


\tikzset{test2/.style={green}}% Sets the style

\tikzset{test2/.provide style={red}}% Doesn't overwrites the style!

% Do we get the green light?
\tikz \fill [test2] (0,0) circle (5pt);

\end{document}
```

Comment: Just for the reference. `\tikzstyle` is used 8 times in v2.10 manual (`{every node}=[...]` on pages 177, 178, 178, 422, 430, 432, 441 and `{every picture}+=[...]` on page 199). I agree that using undocumented macro is a bit dangerous, but in this case its intent is clearly readable. I may also add that I like it for its conciseness.

Comment: @przemoc: The issue with `\tikzstyle` is that it is not easily parseable and adding new handlers like `code` (`/.code`), `style 2 args`, etc. etc. would be difficult. Using the key=value system itself is much more flexible. Personally I find `\tikzset{foo/.append style={bar}}` much nicer looking than `\tikzstyle{foo}+=[bar]`

Comment: re issue - it's meant (from what I can tell) only for pure styles, or with 1 argument. If you have some other stuff, then sure, `\tikzset` is more robust.

Comment: @przemoc: I heard that `\tikzstyle` is an early macro which is deprecated in favor of the official `\tikzset`.

Comment: According to the source, `\tikzoption` is deprecated but there's no such notice for `\tikzstyle` and, indeed, `\tikzstyle` is used extensively in the main code (59 times).