# How to install PGF 2.10 in Ubuntu?

Tags: tikz-pgf, installing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to install a current version of TikZ?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2044/how-to-install-a-current-version-of-tikz)

I have got PGF 2.00 installed, and I would like to upgrade it to 2.10.

`sudo apt-get install pgf` still installs 2.00 under my system. So I went to the website : http://sourceforge.net/projects/pgf/, downloaded the package. I have checked `doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf`, but there are not enough details about installation.

Could anyone help?

By the way, it requires `the xcolor package version 2.00 or higher`. Does anyone know how to check that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a folder called `texmf` in your home folder and unpack the zip file in there (so that you have folders `~/textmf/tex` etc.). That will override the files installed by Ubuntu. (That also means if Ubuntu ever upgrades to a post-2.10 version, you'll still use your locally installed 2.10.)

As to xcolor, it's unfortunately difficult for version within LaTeX, which traditionally goes by release date. The following should work in a Terminal window:

```
grep -A1 ProvidesPackage `kpsewhich xcolor.sty`
```

which here yields

```
\ProvidesPackage{xcolor}
 [2007/01/21 v2.11 LaTeX color extensions (UK)]
```

so you're pretty likely to have a recent enough version of xcolor.

Comment: Indeed. It's quite fortunate that `pgf` is shipped in a form that doesn't require running latex on a .ins file or anything. Just unzip in `$HOME/texmf` and you're golden.

Comment: Thank you... I've checked `xcolor`, its version is fine. I have unpacked the zip file to `~/textmf/tex/pgf_2.10.tds`, and checked its version by [this way](http://cameron.bracken.bz/automated-way-to-check-for-pgf-version), but it still returns 2.10...

Comment: @SoftTimur: typo? It's texmf, only one t.

Comment: Sorry, I meant `~/texmf/tex/pgf_2.10.tds`...

Comment: Sorry, I was unclear in the description. After unpacking, you should have paths like `~/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/...`, `~/texmf/tex/latex/pgf/...`, everything but the `texmf` is already properly in the zip.

Comment: Cool, that works... By the way, I have already something in `~/texmf/tex/latex/` before (a `CJK` folder), so I have added `pgf` folder under it without touching `CJK`...