# matrix with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, tikz-matrix

I would like to reproduce the diagram in 2.1 of https://www3.nd.edu/~wgd/Dvi/CalculatingSimplicialLocalizations.pdf

[image]

So far  I have this piece of code but I don't know how to fill cells with horizontal lines as in the link above:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix[matrix of math nodes]{

  & C_{0,1} & C_{0,2} &    &  \cdots       &        & C_{0,n-1} &   \\

  &         &         &    &               &        &           &   \\

X &         &         &    &               &        &           & Y \\

  &         &         &    &               &        &           &   \\

  &         &         &    &               &          &         &   \\

};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: You might want to use `tikz-cd` package for this purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make lines with a matrix as base you will need to name the matrix and use `\path`. I removed your empty columns and used this example as reference: http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/commutative-diagram-tikz/

To make the vertical dots I create named nodes in the middle of the edges that go from the second row to the last row. I fill each node with white to hide the edge and add another edge from the second row to the node to get the arrow.

Unfortunately `\vdots` has extra space on top, so instead I used the alternative presented here: [How to vertically center the \vdots in this node?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/112204/how-to-vertically-center-the-vdots-in-this-node)

The forth row is empty and has no height. To make sure X and Y appear centered you need to add some phantom content to the row, like `\phantom{C}`.

```
% vertical dots without extra space on top
\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\rvdots}{%
  \vbox{
    \baselineskip4\p@\lineskiplimit\z@
    \kern-\p@
    \hbox{.}\hbox{.}\hbox{.}
  }}
\makeatother

\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (m) [matrix of math nodes,row sep=2em,column sep=2em]{
  & C_{0,1} & C_{0,2} & \cdots & C_{0,n-1}   &   \\
  & C_{1,1} & C_{1,2} & \cdots & C_{1,n-1}   &   \\
X &         &         &        &             & Y \\
  &         &         &        & \phantom{C} &   \\
  & C_{k,1} & C_{k,2} & \cdots & C_{k,n-1}   &   \\
};
\path[-stealth]
    % X
    (m-3-1) edge [-] (m-1-2)
            edge [-] (m-2-2)
            edge [-] (m-5-2)
    % first row
    (m-1-2) edge [-] (m-1-3)
            edge (m-2-2)
    (m-1-3) edge [-] (m-1-4)
            edge (m-2-3)
    (m-1-4) edge [-] (m-1-5)
    (m-1-5) edge [-] (m-3-6)
            edge (m-2-5)
    % second row
    (m-2-2) edge [-] (m-2-3)
            edge node(vdots-2) [fill=white] {$\rvdots$} (m-5-2)
            edge (vdots-2)
    (m-2-3) edge [-] (m-2-4)
            edge node(vdots-3) [fill=white] {$\rvdots$} (m-5-3)
            edge (vdots-3)
    (m-2-4) edge [-] (m-2-5)
    (m-2-5) edge [-] (m-3-6)
            edge node(vdots-5) [fill=white] {$\rvdots$} (m-5-5)
            edge (vdots-5)
    % last row
    (m-5-2) edge [-] (m-5-3)
    (m-5-3) edge [-] (m-5-4)
    (m-5-4) edge [-] (m-5-5)
    (m-5-5) edge [-] (m-3-6)
    % Y is (m-3-6)
;
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: Screenshot from pdf at 200%]

Answer (score 6):

This can be done by `tikz-cd`, `xy` or pure `pstricks` and `tikz`.

I introduced some dimensions (e.g. [-2\jot]). You may want to modify or delete them until the diagram fits your desired style.

Here you are:

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\rvdots}{%
    \vbox{
        \baselineskip4\p@\lineskiplimit\z@
        \kern-\p@
        \hbox{.}\hbox{.}\hbox{.}
    }}
    \makeatother

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{tikzcd}
& C_{0,1}\arrow[dash]{r}\arrow{d} & C_{0,2}\arrow[dash]{r}\arrow{d} &[-2\jot] \cdots\arrow[dash]{r} &[-2\jot] C_{0,n-1}\arrow{d} & \\
& C_{1,1}\arrow[dash]{r}\arrow{dd} & C_{1,2}\arrow[dash]{r}\arrow{dd} & \cdots\arrow[dash]{r} & C_{1,n-1}\arrow{dd} & \\
X \arrow[dash]{uur}\arrow[dash]{ur}\arrow[dash]{ddr} &&&&& Y\arrow[dash]{uul}\arrow[dash]{ul}\arrow[dash]{ddl} \\[-7.2\jot]
& \rvdots \arrow{d} & \rvdots \arrow{d} && \rvdots \arrow{d} & \\
& C_{k,1}\arrow[dash]{r} & C_{k,2}\arrow[dash]{r} & \cdots\arrow[dash]{r} & C_{k,n-1} &
\end{tikzcd}
\tag{*}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hello, thanks a lot! Unfortunetely I have the following error : ! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/dash' and I am going to i
gnore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.  I use the class scrbook.

Comment: I don't know why but instead of your horizontal bars I have horizontal arrows. Any idea ?

Comment: Where I have to write \listfiles ?

Comment: I have Package: tikz-cd 2012/03/18 v0.2b Commutative diagrams with tikz.

Comment: What is the line of command I have to write in the terminal please ?

Comment: @Asymptotik I do not know, what system you are having. Please read the several posts on how to update packages on this site. I will delete my comments here, as it is getting too long without any information for others.

Comment: linux ubuntu 3.2.0

Comment: @Asymptotik http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2044 and http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31727

Comment: I don't understand, nothing works.

Comment: @Asymptotik You have to update your packages or you have to take another approach. Or you leave the `dash`s away from my example if you can live with some arrow heads. See here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/55459 I can't help you to update your TeX distribution here in comments. Please read the multiple help pages for that stuff or ask a new question if you fail to do so.

Answer (score 4):

Similar to LaRiFaRi, but with less dramatic length for the vertical arrows to the dots. The trick is to use mock rows and shortening `row sep`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\newcommand{\cvdots}{\raisebox{-.4ex}[0pt][0pt]{$\vdots$}\mathstrut}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=1em]
 & C_{0,1} \arrow[dddl,dash] \arrow[r,dash] \arrow[dd]
 & C_{0,2} \arrow[r,dash] \arrow[dd]
 & \cdots \arrow[r,dash]
 & C_{0,n-1} \arrow[dddr,dash] \arrow[dd]
\\ \\
 & C_{1,1} \arrow[dl,dash] \arrow[r,dash] \arrow[dd]
 & C_{1,2} \arrow[r,dash] \arrow[dd]
 & \cdots \arrow[r,dash]
 & C_{1,n-1} \arrow[dr,dash] \arrow[dd]
\\
X \arrow[dddr,dash] & & & & & Y \arrow[dddl,dash]
\\
& \cvdots \arrow[dd] & \cvdots \arrow[dd] & & \cvdots \arrow[dd]
\\ \\
 & C_{k,1} \arrow[r,dash]
 & C_{k,2} \arrow[r,dash]
 & \cdots \arrow[r,dash]
 & C_{k,n-1}
\end{tikzcd}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: much easier would be to use `\\[-7.2\jot]` in the third row (resulting in arrow heads on base-line of X. Same procedure could be done for each column. `&[-2\jot]` for the third and fourth separator for example. Just discovered that short time ago, that's why I share it here.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi Interesting! Why don't you add it to your answer?

Comment: fits more into yours as it is more about spacing the cells relative to each other. But well, I will do so.

Comment: Hello, thanks a lot for the beautiful diagram. Unfortunetely I have the following error: ! Arrow direction argument must contain only the characters l, r, u or d. I use the class scrbook.

Answer (score 2):

A bit unfriendly in places, but it pretty much does the job...

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}
\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1.5cm,y=1.25cm,>=stealth]
\foreach \i [count=\y] in {0,1,\vdots,k}
  \foreach \j [count=\x] in {1,2,\ldots,n-1}
    \node (C-\y-\x) at (\x,-\y+2.5) 
      {$\ifnum\y=3\ifnum\x=3\else\i\fi\else\ifnum\x=3\j\else C_{\i,\j}\fi\fi$};
\node at (0,0) (X) {$X$};
\node at (5,0) (Y) {$Y$};    
\foreach \j in {1,2,4}{
  \foreach \i [count=\k from 2] in {1,2,3}
     \draw [->] (C-\j-\i) -- (C-\j-\k) (C-\i-\j) -- (C-\k-\j);
  \draw (X) -- (C-\j-1) (C-\j-4) -- (Y);
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]