# How to add a condition in \tikzset?

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, conditionals

I am trying to make some modification on [the answer of Andrew Stacey](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27278/a-macro-of-drawing-a-rectangle-with-several-parameters-in-tikz) of my previous question "A macro of drawing a rectangle with several parameters in TikZ".

The current code is the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}

\tikzset{
  my funny rectangle/.style n args={4}{%
    rectangle,
    draw,
    append after command={\pgfextra{\let\mainnode=\tikzlastnode}
      node[above right] at (\mainnode.north west) {#3}%
      node[above left] at (\mainnode.north east) {#4}%
      node[below left] at (\mainnode.north west) {#1}%
      node[above left] at (\mainnode.south west) {#2}%
    },
  }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[my funny rectangle={1}{7}{4}{8}] {a text};
\node[my funny rectangle={$i$}{$i$}{4}{8}, text width={3cm}, minimum height={3cm}, text centered] (abc) at (5,5) {text};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I would like to add a condition inside the `append after command`: if `#1` = `#2`, do only `node[below left] at (\mainnode.west) {#1}`, else do `node[below left] at (\mainnode.north west) {#1}` and `node[above left] at (\mainnode.south west) {#2}`.

The answer that @Werner suggested works fine for arguments like `{1}{7}{4}{8}`, but does not work for arguments like `{$i$}{$i$}{4}{8}`. Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: You will need to define the test condition for clarity in your question, what is #1 and #2?

Comment: @Yiannis Lazarides: just made it clearer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably what you're after:

[image]

The standard TeX conditional `\ifx#1#2 <true> \else <false> \fi` works in this case, executing `<true>` if `#1`=`#2` and `<false>` otherwise.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
%\url{http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/27278/86}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}

\tikzset{
  my funny rectangle/.style n args={4}{%
    rectangle,
    draw,
    fit={(#3,#1) (#4,#2)},
    append after command={\pgfextra{\let\mainnode=\tikzlastnode}
      node[above right] at (\mainnode.north west) {#3}%
      node[above left] at (\mainnode.north east) {#4}%
      \ifx#1#2
        node[left] at (\mainnode.west) {#1}%
      \else
        node[below left] at (\mainnode.north west) {#1}%
        node[above left] at (\mainnode.south west) {#2}%
      \fi
    },
  }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[my funny rectangle={1}{1}{4}{8}] {text};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

**Edit**: Here's the updated code that addresses passing some non-numeric arguments to `my funny rectangle`. With the node no longer `fit`ted, you need to specify additional width and height parameters:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}% http://ctan.org/pkg/pgf
%\usetikzlibrary{fit}

\tikzset{
  my funny rectangle/.style n args={4}{%
    rectangle,
    draw,
    %fit={(#3,#1) (#4,#2)},
    append after command={\pgfextra{%
      \let\mainnode=\tikzlastnode%
      \def\argone{#1}\def\argtwo{#2}}
      node[above right] at (\mainnode.north west) {#3}%
      node[above left] at (\mainnode.north east) {#4}%
      \ifx\argone\argtwo
        node[left] at (\mainnode.west) {#1}%
      \else
        node[below left] at (\mainnode.north west) {#1}%
        node[above left] at (\mainnode.south west) {#2}%
      \fi
    },
  }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[my funny rectangle={$i$}{$i$}{4}{8}, text width={3cm}, minimum height={3cm}, text centered] (abc) at (5,5) {text};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks... one thing is... it seems that `ifx` checks only numbers, but I often have for instance `\node[my funny rectangle={$i$}{$i$}{4}{8}] {text};`, do you have any idea?

Comment: @SoftTimur: Is that version going to work with the main code?  Since the numbers are used also as coordinates then I would be a little surprised to discover that `$i$` was an acceptable argument.  The definition might need a little reworking if you want to label the corners by something other than their coordinates.

Comment: @SoftTimur: As Andrew mentioned, the problem is not so much with `\ifx`, but rather with the use of the arguments to specify the text block size/dimension, and `$i$` has no number value.

Comment: @AndrewStacey and @Werner: sorry, actually I did not use `fit={(#3,#1) (#4,#2)}` in my code, but specified the wight and height in `\node` (e.g. `\node[my funny rectangle={1}{1}{$i$}{$i$}, text width={3cm},  minimum height={3cm}, text centered] (abc) at (5,5) {text}`). In this case, without the condition, the macro does accept `$i$`, so i would like to make the condition accept this kind of arguments.

Comment: @SoftTimur: Please modify your original question to reflect this change.

Comment: @Werner: just done

Comment: @SoftTimur: How about updating your post with a [complete, working minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that shows exactly what the new structure of `\tikzset` is. Otherwise any attempts to solve this might be subject to slight nuances in your code, leading to more confusion.

Comment: @Werner: just did it

Comment: So then `\def\argone{#1}\def\argtwo{#2} ... \ifx\argone\argtwo` ought to do it, shouldn't it?

Comment: @AndrewStacey: I tried that, but I'm not sure where to make this assignment in the macro, since the contents of `\tikzset` are key-value pairs. Putting it in `\pgfextra{...}` doesn't help either.

Comment: Putting the assignment in `\pgfextra` works for me.  Note that the assignment `\let\mainnode=\tikzlastnode` is in the `\pgfextra` so there's no grouping issues there.  What really confused me is that SoftTimur put the doubled argument on the *big* square, not the little one!  So I thought that the conditional was being evaluated the wrong way around.

Comment: Cool, Andrew Stacey's solution works for me... For instance `\pgfextra{\let\mainnode=\tikzlastnode \def\argone{#1}\def\argtwo{#2}\def\argthree{#3}\def\argfour{#4}}` ... `\ifx\argone\argtwo` ...