# A condition in \tikzset

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, conditionals

I would like to set a drawing option to decorate lines with a circle of a color of my choice, with "none" meaning no circle. I am hoping for something like this:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, decorations.markings}
\tikzset{-o-/.style n args={1}{
append after command={\pgfextra{\let\mainnode=\tikzlastnode}% Borrowed this line, but I don't understand it.
\def\argone{#1} \def\argtwo{none}
\ifx\argone\argtwo
\else
decoration={markings, mark=at position 0.5 with {draw[black, fill=#1] circle[radius=2pt];}}, postaction={decorate}
\fi
}}}

\newcommand*{\mytriangle}[1]{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[-o-={#1}] (0,0)--(0,1);
\draw[-o-={#1}] (0,0)--(1,0);
\draw[-o-={#1}] (1,0)--(0,1);
\end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{document}
\mytriangle{white}, \mytriangle{none}.
\end{document}
```

I tried to borrow

```
append after command={\pgfextra{...} ...}
```

from [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31741/how-to-add-a-condition-in-tikzset), since otherwise ifx conditional does not work inside of \tikzset, but now my code does not make the desired decorations.

Comment: Why don't you set your test within `\mytriangle` instead of `\tikzset`?

Comment: I want to use it in a large number of tikz pictures.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use a `.code` type and invoke `\pgfkeysalso` inside the code instead of evaluating the conditional inside a `.style`. Internally a `.style` is just that, `\tikzset{foo/.style={bar}}` does the same as `\tikzset{foo/.code=\pgfkeysalso{bar}}`, but in `.code` you can evaluate arbitrary code, and not only call `\pgfkeysalso`.

Note that you don't need `append after command` for this (you're using the `decorations.markings` library for the placement of the code).

I borrowed `\str_if_eq:nnF` from `expl3` for this (your `\def\argone{#1}\def\argtwo{none}\ifx` test could work, too, but might have unwanted side effects of redefining the two macros `\argone` and `\argtwo`, you'd have to put a group around that test for it to be safe).

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_eq:NN \ifstreqF \str_if_eq:nnF
\ExplSyntaxOff

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, decorations.markings}
\tikzset
  {
    -o-/.code=%
      {%
        \ifstreqF{#1}{none}
          {%
            \pgfkeysalso
              {
                decoration=%
                  {%
                    markings,
                    mark=at position 0.5 with {\draw[black, fill={#1}]
                      circle[radius=2pt];}
                  },
                postaction={decorate}
              }
          }
      }
  }

\newcommand*{\mytriangle}[1]{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[-o-={#1}] (0,0)--(0,1);
\draw[-o-={#1}] (0,0)--(1,0);
\draw[-o-={#1}] (1,0)--(0,1);
\end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{document}
\mytriangle{white}, \mytriangle{none}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Side note on your test: The following would be a working and safe variant of it:

```
\begingroup
  \def\argone{#1}%
  \def\argtwo{none}%
  \expandafter
\endgroup
\ifx\argone\argtwo
  <true>
\else
  <false>
\fi
```

The `\begingroup ...\endgroup` keeps the definitions of `\argone` and `\argtwo` local, and thanks to `\expandafter` the `\ifx` is evaluated before the definitions of `\argone` and `\argtwo` are restored by the end of the group.

Comment: Thanks, that works great! As it was a minimal example, now I am trying to add the position of the circle as the second argument, so that I can use \draw[-o-={white}{0.5}] .... I tried \tikzset{-o-/.code with n args={2}{\ifstreqF{#1}{none {\pgfkeysalso{decoration={markings, mark=at position #2 with {\draw[black, fill={#1}] circle[radius=2pt];}},postaction={decorate}} but it doesn't work...

Comment: @Adam because the correct name is `.code n args` without the `with`, also, for 2 args, consider using `.code 2 args` instead.

Comment: Of course. Thanks!

Comment: @Adam but first take a look at the documentation of `.code 2 args`, it differs from `.code n args={2}{...}`, which you could take advantage of, if you so wanted.