# Tikz package. How to build a rectangle centered in one point?

Tags: tikz-pgf

For istance, with Tikz, I can draw a circle centered in the point (0,0) with radius 2. How can I draw a rectangle centerd in (0,0) giving height and basis?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Last but not least, you could use a node, whose shape is rectangle and apply its anchor to its center:

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    % I want to center the rectangle here
    \filldraw (0,0) node [below] {center here} circle (1pt);
    % drawing the node with shape=rectangle and anchor=center
    \node [draw, thick, shape=rectangle, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=2cm, anchor=center] at (0,0) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `shift` key:

```
 \draw[shift={(2,1)}] (-3,-2) rectangle (3,2);
```

With this method, you can also rotate the rectangle around the center:

```
 \draw[shift={(2,1)},rotate=20] (-3,-2) rectangle (3,2);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use the tikzpackage calc you can achieve this quite easily.

If A is the center and dim the basis/height of the rectangle

```
\coordinate (A) at (2,2);
\coordinate (dim) at (3,4);
```

you could calculate the lower left and upper right coordinate with:

```
\coordinate (LL) at ($(A)-0.5*(dim)$);
\coordinate (UR) at ($(A)+0.5*(dim)$);
```

And then draw the rectangle between those two points.

If you need this often I recommend creating a macro for it - se here:
[A macro of drawing a rectangle with several parameters in TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27278/a-macro-of-drawing-a-rectangle-with-several-parameters-in-tikz)