# How to make nodes to simple dots instead of being named

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

I currently have the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
\tikzstyle{every node}=[draw,shape=circle]
\path (0,0) node (p0) {$p_0$}
(-1.5,-1) node (p1) {$p_1$}
(-1.5,-2.5) node (p2) {$p_2$}
(1.5,-2.5) node (p3) {$p_3$}
(1.5,-1) node (p4) {$p_4$}
(0,-3.5) node (p5) { $p_5$};
\draw (p0) -- (p1)
(p0) -- (p1)
(p0) -- (p2)
(p0) -- (p3)
(p0) -- (p4)
(p0) -- (p5)
(p1) -- (p2)
(p1) -- (p3)
(p1) -- (p4)
(p1) -- (p5)
(p2) -- (p3)
(p2) -- (p4)
(p2) -- (p5)
(p3) -- (p4)
(p3) -- (p5)
(p4) -- (p5);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

but my problem is that this name each node. And i just want a simple dot.
How do I do that?

Comment: Just take out the `$p_k$` bits.  The names for later referral are in the `(pk)` bits so are still there.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you remove the `$p_1$`,...,`$p_6$` from your code then you obtain

[image]

On another note, have a look at

[Is there something like \providetikzstyle similar to \providecommand?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22640/is-there-something-like-providetikzstyle-similar-to-providecommand)

which details that `\tikzstyle` isn't an ideal command to use. I've used an alternative in my code below.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={draw,shape=circle,fill=blue}]
\path (0,0) node (p0) {}
(-1.5,-1) node (p1) {}
(-1.5,-2.5) node (p2) {}
(1.5,-2.5) node (p3) {}
(1.5,-1) node (p4) {}
(0,-3.5) node (p5) { };
\draw (p0) -- (p1)
(p0) -- (p1)
(p0) -- (p2)
(p0) -- (p3)
(p0) -- (p4)
(p0) -- (p5)
(p1) -- (p2)
(p1) -- (p3)
(p1) -- (p4)
(p1) -- (p5)
(p2) -- (p3)
(p2) -- (p4)
(p2) -- (p5)
(p3) -- (p4)
(p3) -- (p5)
(p4) -- (p5);
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Comment: yea thats it.. can you say anything about changing the node size?

Comment: @Andreas is that part of your question? :) you can try for example `minimum size=2cm`

Comment: Its a follow up question i guess:) because I think the size of the nodes are to large.. and how would u use that size=2cm ?

Comment: @Andreas no problem :) try `...,fill=blue,scale=0.5}` for example. adjust as necessary

Comment: @Andreas: Use `minimum size=<length>` and `inner sep=<length>`. Both will make the node bigger than the included content. Then there is always the `coordinate` node type, i.e. use `\coordinate` instead of `\node` or `\path .. coordinate .. ` instead of `\path .. node ..`. These nodes have zero size, are not displayed at all and can't have any content.

Comment: @cmhughes The figure does not match the code. `\x` and `\y` are exchanged.

Answer (score 15):

Personally in this case I prefer the syntax `coordinate (p) at (x,y)` (I know that it's the same things but I don't like `{}`.

Then the code can be :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[dot/.style={draw,circle,minimum size=2mm,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,fill=blue}]
\path \foreach \x/\y [count=\k from 0] in { 0/0,  -1.5/-1, -1.5/-2.5,  1.5/-2.5, 1.5/-1,  0/-3.5}
         {coordinate [dot] (p\k) at (\x,\y)}; 
\draw \foreach \k [count=\j from 1] in {0,...,4}
         \foreach \kk  in {\j,...,5}  
            {(p\k)--(p\kk)};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hehe, so I'm not the only one prefering `foreach` loops ;)

Comment: @TomBombadil: `\draw \foreach` for the win!

Comment: +1 I'll vote for this tomorrow (when I have a new batch of votes, I'm all out for today), nice solution :)

Answer (score 5):

You could also reduce your code a lot by using `foreach` loops. Also it's a good idea to specify parameters via macros, that way you can easily alter the look of your picture. In this example, the node size, node distance and node fillcolor can be changed by just changing the initial commands:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\pgfmathsetmacro{\minsize}{0.2cm}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\nodedist}{3}
\newcommand{\fillcolor}{black}


\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
\tikzstyle{every node}=[draw,shape=circle,minimum size=\minsize,inner sep=0]
\foreach \x in {0,...,5}
    \node[fill=\fillcolor] (p\x) at (\x*60:\nodedist) {};
\foreach \x in {0,...,4}    
{   \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\startvalue}{\x+1}
    \foreach \y in {\startvalue,...,5}
    {\draw (p\x) -- (p\y);
    }
}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]