# Choosing styles conditionally in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, conditionals, tikz-styles

I want to create a series of images that visualise a recursion tree as walked on by an algorithm. That means that different styles are applied to nodes depending on the step the algorithm is in, such as hiding, highlighting, etc. Consider this example:

[image: example]
<sup>[[source](https://github.com/akerbos/sesketches/blob/gh-pages/src/tex_55948.tex)]</sup>

As you can see, some styles are (not) applied "from image i on"; for instance, `hidden` nodes become `unvisited` (grayed out) and then normal, but never change back. Other styles are applied more flexibly, for example the yellowish highlighting `active` (which shows what node the visualised algorithm currently investigates). Above image was created by explicitly writing code for six images. Naturally, I want to avoid duplicating code as much as possible.

I thought that the following should be a straightforward way to achieve this:

```
\tikzset{<TikZ style definitions>}
\newcommand{\image}[1]{<TikZ image code>}
\begin{document}
  \foreach \n in {1,...,<N>}{%
    \image{\n}
  }
\end{document}
```

Now, `\image` has to choose styles depending on parameter `#1` (i.e. `\n`); I am fine with hardcoding which style is applied on which image numbers.

But neither

```
\node \ifthenelse{<condition>}{[style=<name>]}{} {<label>};
```

nor

```
\node[\ifthenelse{<condition>}{style=<name>}{}] {<label>};
```

works. So I tried to use `ifthenelse` inside the (now parametric) style definition, which also failed, and then put

```
\tikzset{%
  test/.code={\ifthenelse{<condition>}{style=<name>}{}}
}
```

in the preamble, together with

```
\node[test=<param>] {<label>};
```

in the image; this does not work, either.

> How can I choose TikZ styles conditionally?

A feasible workaround might be to create the nodes conditionally (i.e. duplicating node definitions for each case), but this is nasty for trees. Therefore, I would prefer a more surgical solution.

I use `xifthen` for conditions, in particular `\isin`. For example, I try assigning style `active` by checking

```
\ifthenelse{\isin{!#1!}{!1!2!4!6!}}{<set style active>}{<no style>}
```

in the case of root node `a`, where `#1` is the parameter of `\image`. Ideally, I would be able to put such a statement at every affected node, that is the information which style is applied on which image is defined locally at the styled elements (for all images at once).

Comment: Using `\node \ifnum#1=1 [style 1]\fi {<label>};` works fine. I think that you might get better answers if you made your question a little more concrete: What are the styles going to change, are they always going to be used in a loop, how many different options will you need? This can probably be solved more elegantly if the problem is described more concretely.

Comment: @Jake I already said that I needed more complex conditions than number equality. I will include a small example tomorrow, though, if there is no answer till then.

Comment: I have been using the solution from [Is there something like `\providetikzstyle` similar to `\providecommand`?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22640/is-there-something-like-providetikzstyle-similar-to-providecommand), although it really should be `\providetikzset` based on [Should `\tikzset` or `\tikzstyle` be used to define TikZ styles?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52372/should-tikzset-or-tikzstyle-be-used-to-define-tikz-styles).

Comment: For those interested, see [here](http://verrech.net/sefiles/cs_1016.tex) how it turned out.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A really simple approach would probably be to use the image number directly to index the style:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{
    image/.cd,
    1/.style={fill=orange},
    2/.style={fill=yellow},
    3/.style={fill=cyan}
}

\newcommand{\image}[1]{
    \tikz{ \draw [image/#1] circle [radius=1cm];}
}

\begin{document}
  \foreach \n in {1,...,3}{%
    \expandafter\image\expandafter{\n}
  }
\end{document}
```

However, as Jake pointed out, a more complex selection scheme is probably wanted by the OP, who in particular mentioned a "parametric style". The following uses Jake's example, but moves the testing from the macro to the style definition:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xifthen}

\tikzset{
    image/.cd,
    1/.style={fill=orange},
    2/.style={fill=yellow},
    3/.style={fill=cyan},
    test/.code={%
      \ifthenelse{\isin{#1}{ABC}}{\tikzset{image/1}}{
      \ifthenelse{\isin{#1}{DEF}}{\tikzset{image/2}}{
      \ifthenelse{\isin{#1}{GHI}}{\tikzset{image/3}}{
      }}}
    },
}

\newcommand{\image}[1]{
    \tikz{ \draw [image/test=#1] circle [radius=1cm];}
}

\begin{document}
  \foreach \n in {A,E,G}{%
    \expandafter\image\expandafter{\n}
  }
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I don't think the OP is actually using numbers in their application, but strings and substrings. At least that's what I gather from their last sentence "I use `xifthen` for conditions, in particular `\isin`." and the somewhat testy "I already said that I needed more complex conditions than number equality.".

Comment: @Jake: Hm... I now found the `\isin` part, but I must still be overlooking where they already said that more complex conditions are needed. I will wait for a more complete MWE that details these constraints.

Comment: Sorry, that last bit was in reply to my comment on their question.

Comment: @Jake: No, that was fine. I had found the comment, but still do not know to what exactly the already in "as I already said" refers. Said where? Anyway, I have improved my solution that now resembles yours, but with the tests in the style definition.

Comment: Ah yes, now I understand. Nice answer!

Comment: Aha, so it's `\tikzset{<style name>}` instead of the `style=<name>` I tried. That seems to work, thanks!

Answer (score 14):

A style may define other styles... So, no test ! ;-)

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{
   set styles 1/.style={
     circle style/.style={fill=red},
     square style/.style={fill=orange},
   },
   set styles 2/.style={
     circle style/.style={fill=cyan},
     square style/.style={fill=violet,fill opacity=.5},
   },
   set styles A/.style={
     circle style/.style={draw},
     square style/.style={fill=violet,fill opacity=.5},
   },
}
\newcommand\image[1]{
  \begin{scope}[set styles #1]
    \path[circle style] circle [radius=.6cm];
    \path[square style] (-.5,-.5) rectangle (.5,.5);
  \end{scope}
}

\begin{document}

\foreach \n in {1,2,A}{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \image{\n}
  \end{tikzpicture}
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Here, your example with this approach:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[paperwidth=4cm,paperheight=3.25cm,margin=.10cm]{geometry}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{%
  active/.style={fill=yellow!30},
  unvisited/.style={opacity=.2},
  hidden/.style={opacity=0},
  lb/.style={color=green!70!black},
  ub/.style={color=red!70!black},
  ind exp/.style={scale=.7},
  step 1/.style={
    a/.style={active},
    b/.style={},
    c/.style={},
    a b/.style={hidden},
    a c/.style={hidden},
    a ind/.style={lb},
    a exp/.style={hidden},
    b ind/.style={hidden},
    b exp/.style={hidden},
    c ind/.style={hidden},
    c exp/.style={hidden},
  },
  step 2/.style={
    step 1,
    a b/.style={unvisited},
    a c/.style={unvisited},
    b ind/.style={lb},
    c ind/.style={lb},
  },
  step 3/.style={
    step 2,
    a/.style={},
    b/.style={active},
    a b/.style={},
    b exp/.style={ub},
  },
  step 4/.style={
    step 3,
    a/.style={active},
    b/.style={},
    a exp/.style={ub},
  },
  step 5/.style={
    step 4,
    a/.style={},
    c/.style={active},
    a c/.style={},
    c exp/.style={ub},
  },
  step 6/.style={
    step 5,
    a/.style={active},
    c/.style={},
  },
}

\newcommand\mypict[2]{
  \begin{tikzpicture}[level 1/.style={sibling distance=10mm}]
    \begin{scope}[step #1]    
      \node [a] (a) {$[a]$}
      child [a b] { node[b] (b) {$[b]$} }
      child [a c] { node[c] (c) {$[c]$} };

      \node[a ind,ind exp,below right=-3.5mm and -2mm of a] {$5$};
      \node[a exp,ind exp,above right=-3.5mm and -2mm of a] {$#2$};

      \node[b ind,ind exp,below right=-3.5mm and -2mm of b] {$6$};
      \node[b exp,ind exp,above right=-3.5mm and -2mm of b] {$7$};

      \node[c ind,ind exp,below right=-3.5mm and -2mm of c] {$5$};
      \node[c exp,ind exp,above right=-3.5mm and -2mm of c] {$5$};

      \node[right=1cm of a,scale=.7] {$p#1$};
    \end{scope}
  \end{tikzpicture}
}

\foreach \n/\aexp in {1/5,2/5,3/5,4/7,5/7,6/5}{
  \mypict{\n}{\aexp}
  \clearpage
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is very nice, but I don't think it addresses the OPs requirement of checking for the presence of a substring in a larger string (as indicated by the hint that "I use `xifthen` for conditions, in particular `\isin`"). Though they never disclosed *why* they need those kinds of conditionals, so maybe this solution is exactly what they're looking for...

Comment: You're probably right (I missed his first comment). Perhaps he will say more tomorrow.

Comment: @Jake: Maybe you skipped my first paragraph. I agree it might not be clear what precisely my needs are, but "the never disclosed why" is clearly not true. Anyway, I'll edit later.

Comment: I added an example. As it is, your solution would require me to define the same styles multiple times; is this the most efficient way to do things?

Comment: @Raphael I added your example to my solution.  I'm not sure this is the most efficient way but it works and the factorization is good.

Comment: @PolGab: Thanks! It is definitely a nice solution. Compared to Daniel's approach, which one works better depends on taste (his is node-focused, yours step-focused) and how much styles change (his is more efficient for few changes, yours for many).

Answer (score 10):

You could use a "variable" style in your drawing that is set to the desired value according to your condition before the drawing command:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xifthen}
\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{
    current style/.style={},
    first/.style={fill=orange},
    second/.style={fill=yellow},
    third/.style={fill=cyan}
}

\newcommand{\image}[1]{
    \ifthenelse{\isin{#1}{ABC}}{\tikzset{current style/.style=first}}{
        \ifthenelse{\isin{#1}{DEF}}{\tikzset{current style/.style=second}}{
            \ifthenelse{\isin{#1}{GHI}}{\tikzset{current style/.style=third}}{}
        }
    }
    \tikz{ \draw [current style] circle [radius=1cm];}
}

\begin{document}
  \foreach \n in {A,E,G}{%
    \expandafter\image\expandafter{\n}
  }
\end{document}
```

Comment: Isn't `/.is choice` more comfortable?

Comment: Well, that depends on what kind of "complex conditions" the OP needs. I don't think you can use the `\isin` string comparison method for `.is choice`, right?

Comment: I don't know. I didn't test it. You are the expert of tikz ;-)