# PGF loop variables in string comparisons

Tags: conditionals, strings, foreach, pgf-core, xifthen

In a [bigger context](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55948/choosing-styles-conditionally-in-tikz), I need to check whether an integer parameter is contained in a set of numbers. I decided to encode sets as strings; elements are separated by `!`. I don't know whether this is the best way to do this, but a curious thing happens:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor,xifthen}

\newcommand{\ifin}[1]{
  \ifthenelse{\isin{!#1!}{!1!3!}}{T}{F}%
}

\begin{document}
\ifin{1}\ifin{2}\ifin{3}\ifin{4}

\foreach \n in {1,...,4} {%
  \ifin{\n}%
}
\end{document}
```

The expected output is

```
TFTF
TFTF
```

but the actual output is

```
TFTF
FFFF
```

Note that `pdflatex` does not report any errors or warnings.

I suspect that this is a more general issue (`\isin` checks whether strings are substrings of other strings; it probably fails because the parameter is a number) but I can not find material on this. How can I achieve the desired behaviour?

Comment: I have been searching for the wrong keywords, probably. Apologies if the question is trivial.

Comment: Use: `\foreach \n in {1,...,4} {%
 \edef\x{\noexpand\ifin{\n}}\x
}`

Comment: or simpler  `  \expandafter\ifin\expandafter{\n}%`

Comment: @Raphael: This is just a warning, before you ask later - as many have done previously. If you're printing the result of your test, you should have no problem with `\foreach`. But if you do any assignment in the scope of `\foreach`, it will be local to that scope/group, and you won't find it outside that scope unless you prefix the assignment with `\global`. Moreover, I hope your example is actually a MWE, since it doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: @AhmedMusa: Thanks for the warning. It is an M(N)WE; check the linked question for my use case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is an expansion issue: the token `\n` is not in your list, as you will agree.

You have to communicate *explicitly* that you want to check for the *value* of `\n` rather than the name `\n`:

```
\foreach \n in {1,...,4} {%
  \expandafter\ifin\expandafter{\n}%
}
```

An alternative is to use `\edef` (like `\edef\temp{\noexpand\ifin{\n}}\temp`).

See http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/TeX-programming-notes.pdf for details on expansion control.

NOTE: I would not be surprised if commands like `\if*` cause trouble if they are used deep inside of some macro. This is caused by TeX's tokenizer; the name interferes with the way TeX handles boolean variables. I would suggest a different prefix (say, `\raphaelifin`).

Comment: actually `\ifin` isn't an `if` in the sense of `\newif` so it's just as safe as `\raphaelifin` to TeX (although confusing toi humans as it _looks_ like an if.