# Changing the properties of an edge on a later slide

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

I am using beamer and TikZ and would like to change the color and thickness of an edge in the second slide of the same frame. Here is what I tried:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,shapes.geometric,arrows,fit,calc,positioning,automata}

\begin{document}

\frame{
    \newcommand*\properties{}
    \only<2>{\renewcommand*{\properties}{orange, ultra thick}}
    \begin{figure}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 1.5cm, scale=0.8]

        \node (1) {1};
        \node[right = of 1] (2) {2};

        \path[->]
        (1) edge[\properties] (2);

        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}
}

\end{document}
```

The strange thing is that when I put only `orange` or only `ultra thick` in the definition of `\properties`, everything works as expected. In addition, if I just put `orange, ultra thick` together in the bracket that follows `edge`, it is still fine (and of course in this case the edge has the same look on both slides). But when I have both of them there, an error occurs:

> Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/orange, ultra thick' and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.

May I know why this is the case? How should I correct it to achieve the desired result (i.e., the edge turning both orange and thicker on the second slide)? Thank you!

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/72958/1952

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think that you can put an `\only...` command inside the edge command like this. Rather, you have to apply `\only...` to a full command.

The following works:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,shapes.geometric,arrows,fit,calc,positioning,automata}

\tikzset{properties/.style={orange, ultra thick}}
\begin{document}

\frame{
    \begin{figure}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 1.5cm, scale=0.8]

        \node (1) {1};
        \node[right = of 1] (2) {2};

        \only<2>{\path[->](1) edge[properties] (2);}
        \only<1,3->{\path[->](1) edge (2);}

        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}
}

\end{document}
```

I have used `\tikzset` to define your properties in the "tikz way". If you are only using this in one `tikzpicture` environment you can also define this "locally" by

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 1.5cm, scale=0.8,
                    properties/.style={orange, ultra thick}]
...
\end{tikzpicture}
```

**Edit I**

As pointed out in [How to modify a node in TikZ when using beamer's overlays](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/72958/how-to-modify-a-node-in-tikz-when-using-beamers-overlays), another way of doing this to use `\only...` to set the properties by writing:

```
\only<1,3->{\tikzset{properties/.style={}}}
\only<2>{\tikzset{properties/.style={orange, ultra thick}}}
```

Now your `tikzpicture` environment is no longer requires any `\only...` statements and for the node you just write:

```
\path[->](1) edge[properties] (2);
```

**Edit II**

Note that anything inside `\only` is local to the frame. You could instead, for example, make

```
\tikzset{properties/.style={orange, ultra thick}}
```

a "global" definition at the in your preamble and then use

```
\only<1,3->{\tikzset{properties/.style={}}}
```

whenever you want to turn this definition "off". Note also that any `\tikzset` inside a frame applies only for that frame and will not be accessible in other frames, so this needs to go into the preamble or, more accurately, outside a frame.

Comment: Thanks! Is the method in your Edit also a local definition? So that I won't have the `properties` style in other frames?

Comment: Yes, it's local. See **Edit II**.

Comment: Thank you a lot! I think you missed a `}` at the end of `\tikzset{properties/.style={orange, ultra thick}}` in **Edit II.**