# pgfplots .provide style similar to tikzset's .provide style

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, tikz-styles

I have been using `tikzset{style name/.provide style={}}`from [Is there something like \providetikzstyle similar to \providecommand?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/22640/4301) defined as

```
\tikzset{/handlers/.provide style/.code={%
    \pgfkeysifdefined{\pgfkeyscurrentpath/.@cmd}{}%
        {\pgfkeys {\pgfkeyscurrentpath /.code=\pgfkeysalso {#1}}}%
}}
```

and have found it very handy.  What is the similar version for `\pgfplotsset`. The following does *not* seem to work:

```
\pgfplotsset{/handlers/.provide style/.code={%
    \pgfkeysifdefined{\pgfkeyscurrentpath/.@cmd}{}%
        {\pgfkeys {\pgfkeyscurrentpath /.code=\pgfkeysalso {#1}}}%
}}
```

The MWE below produces the image on the left, but should produce the image on the right once `.provide style` is working for `\pgfplotsset` (ie, no `x` tick labels and a thick red box):

[image]

### References:

- [Is there something like \providetikzstyle similar to \providecommand?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/22640/4301)

### Code:

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22640/is-there-something-like-providetikzstyle-similar-to-providecommand
\tikzset{/handlers/.provide style/.code={%
    \pgfkeysifdefined{\pgfkeyscurrentpath/.@cmd}{}%
        {\pgfkeys {\pgfkeyscurrentpath /.code=\pgfkeysalso {#1}}}%
}}

%% How to define this???
\pgfplotsset{/handlers/.provide style/.code={%
    \pgfkeysifdefined{\pgfkeyscurrentpath/.@cmd}{}%
        {\pgfkeys {\pgfkeyscurrentpath /.code=\pgfkeysalso {#1}}}%
}}

\begin{document}
\pgfplotsset{tick label style/.provide style={% output should be as if this was ".style" instead of ".provide style"
    xticklabels={},
    draw=red, 
    ultra thick,
}}

%% This should be ignored as it was already defined above.
\pgfplotsset{tick label style/.provide style={
    xticklabels={},
    yticklabels={},
    draw=blue, ultra thick,
}}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[%
    tick label style,% <---- y ticklabels shown, x ticklabels suppressed, axis in red
]
    \addplot {x^2};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I think it doesn't work because it is already defined in the first place

Comment: @percusse: Well, that is rather embarrasing!! I guess I should try to get more sleep!!

Comment: I think `\tikzset` should not be used at the very first place. It suggests that this definition is Ti*k*Z specific but it is not. (And it should not be.)