# Equivalent of \providecoordinate?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, coordinates

I am looking for something that is the equivalent of `\providecoordinate` in TikZ/PGFplots. This would be easy if I knew how to test if a coordinate is already defined.

There are similar questions about [how to implement something which effectively implements `providetikzstyle`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22640/is-there-something-like-providetikzstyle-similar-to-providecommand) and [how to implement `provideenvironment`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20687/does-newenvironment-have-a-provideenvironment-cousin-as-newcommand-has-provi).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `coordinate` in TikZ is a special form of node. The coordinate x/y etc. values of a node is stored in a macro named `\pgf@sh@np@<name>` which existence you can test. The following code should do it and support most variations of the `\coordinate` syntax. Supporting the `\path coordinate` syntax, i.e. allow for `\path providecoordinate` is not possible without extensively hacking into the path parsing code.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\providecoordinate}[1][]{%
    \@providecoordinate[#1]%
}
\def\@providecoordinate[#1]#2(#3)#4;{%
    \ifcsname pgf@sh@np@#3\endcsname\else
        \coordinate[#1]#2(#3)#4;
    \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
   \providecoordinate [] (A) at (0,0);
   \coordinate (B) at (0,0);

   \providecoordinate (B) at (1,0);

   % Small test: Both at the same location? YES!
   \draw [red]   (A) circle (1pt);
   \draw [green] (B) circle (2pt);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```