# Tikz: redefinition of patterns

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgf-core

I save my TikZ figures in separate files containing all the necessary definitions, so it's easy to reuse them.

In some cases I defined a new pattern, e.g. by

```
\pgfdeclarepatternformonly{wide lines}{\pgfqpoint{-1pt}{-1pt}}{\pgfqpoint{12pt}{12pt}}{\pgfqpoint{9pt}{9pt}}%
{
  \pgfsetlinewidth{0.4pt}
  \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{0pt}}
  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{9pt}{9pt}}
  \pgfusepath{stroke}
}
```

However, if I use two such figures in the same document, pdflatex complains about the already defined pattern. Is there any way that I can check if a pattern with that name is already defined, and if yes, just skip my definition?

I looked a bit in the pgf source codes but didn't really understand it.

Comment: I would put the pattern definitions in a separate file and import the definitions file. That way the definitions are kept consistent.

Comment: Related Questions: [\providecoordinate](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23245/equivalent-of-providecoordinate), [\providetikzstyle](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22640/is-there-something-like-providetikzstyle-similar-to-providecommand).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, I would put the pattern definitions in a separate file and import the definitions file. That way the definitions are kept consistent.

However, if you do not want to do that you could use `\providepgfdeclarepatternformonly` instead of `\pgfdeclarepatternformonly` using this definition:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\providepgfdeclarepatternformonly}[4][]{%
    \pgfutil@ifundefined{pgf@pattern@name@#1}{
        \pgfdeclarepatternformonly{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}
    }{%
        %Pattern already defined, so don't redefine it
    }%
}
\makeatother
```

Similar to `providecommand`, if the pattern is already defined the attempt to redefine it is ignored.  Here is the test case where using `providepgfdeclarepatternformonly` compiles, but `pgfdeclarepatternformonly` gives the error about pattern already being defined.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\providepgfdeclarepatternformonly}[5]{%
    \pgfutil@ifundefined{pgf@pattern@name@#1}{%
        \pgfdeclarepatternformonly{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}%
    }{%
        %Pattern already defined, so don't redefine it
    }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\providepgfdeclarepatternformonly{wide lines}{\pgfqpoint{-1pt}{-1pt}}{\pgfqpoint{12pt}{12pt}}{\pgfqpoint{9pt}{9pt}}%
{
  \pgfsetlinewidth{0.4pt}
  \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{0pt}}
  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{9pt}{9pt}}
  \pgfusepath{stroke}
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\providepgfdeclarepatternformonly{wide lines}{\pgfqpoint{-1pt}{-1pt}}{\pgfqpoint{12pt}{12pt}}{\pgfqpoint{9pt}{9pt}}%
{
  \pgfsetlinewidth{0.4pt}
  \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{0pt}}
  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{9pt}{9pt}}
  \pgfusepath{stroke}
}

\filldraw[pattern=wide lines] (0,0) rectangle (2,2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Just as I was about to say ... but you beat me too it.  I agree with your comment to the question, by the way.

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for!