# How to define an environment only if it is not defined yet using etoolbox

Tags: macros

I am not sure which test to use.  This seems to work:

```
\ifcsmacro{myenvironment}{}{
    \newenvironment{myenvironment}{Not seen so far.}{End.}
}
```

Is that ok, or should I use another test?  Moreover, should I not use etoolbox?  I am using etoolbox for other tasks, so using it here seems natural.

Comment: One would thing of `\provideenvironment`, which apparently does not exist. However, http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/20691/3751 presents a pure-Latex implementation of it.

Comment: You should probably also test for `\endmyenvironment` as `\end{myenv}` does `\endmyenv` (after some sanity testing)

Comment: @Daniel:  Thanks for the link to `\provideenvironment`.  I think that could be ok, but I was looking for a simple high level test using `etoolbox`, since I have that package already loaded.  If `\provideenvironment` existed in plain LaTeX, I surely would use it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is sufficient, since LaTeX defines commands `\<env>` and `\end<env>` when you execute `\newenvironment{<env>}`. However, just to be on the safe side, you may want to remove any previous definitions of `\end<env>` that may have been defined using `\def\end<env>{...}` for whatever reason:

```
\ifcsmacro{myenvironment}{}{
  \let\endmyenvironment\undefined%
  \newenvironment{myenvironment}{Not seen so far.}{End.}
}
```

Here, `\undefined` is an undefined macro. It may just as well have been anything that is undefined, like `\thismacrodoesnotexist`. Of course, if there is concern that `\end<env>` might be important, then you should test for that as well before defining `<env>`, possibly by nesting it within the `<false>` condition of `\ifcsmacro`.

Comment: I do not know how the environment was defined, if it was actually defined, so it could be better to take the safe way.  However, I am not sure to understand that part of your answer. Are you trying to ensure that the definition of `\end<end>` will not fail when `\newenvironment` is executed?

Comment: @ASdeL: If someone defined a macro `\end<env>` and you only test for the existence of `\<env>` then performing `\newenvironment{<env>}` would cause an error, since it defines *both* `\<env>` and `\end<env>` (the latter already existing). So, adding `\let\end<env>\undefined` removes any former definition assigned to `\end<env>` so that `\newenvironment{<env>}` does not fail. Does this help?