# How to *not* define command when a package option is called

Tags: beamer, theorems, amsthm, package-writing, package-options

I've recently written my own personal package (let's call it `mypkg`), which contains all the math macros I use on a regular basis. I would like to get this package to work with `beamer`. My package loads `amsthm` and then proceeds to define several theorem environments, e.g. `theorem`, `lemma`, `corollary`, etc. However, this clashes with `beamer`, since `beamer` defines these environments internally as well. Consequently, I get errors when trying to load `mypkg` in a `beamer` document.

What I would like to do is define a `beamer` option in `mypkg`, and then I can call `\usepackage[beamer]{mypkg}` when using `mypkg` in a `beamer` document. I see there is a `\DeclareOption` command which allows you to define certain things if the specified option is declared when calling the package. What I would like to do is *the opposite*; define those theorem environments only if the `beamer` option is **not** entered. How can I do this?

Bonus points if there is a way to automatically feed the `documentclass` to `mypkg` and have it do such things as required.

Comment: Use a `\provideenvironment` to define environments only if necessary: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/20691/193767

Comment: @JairoADelRio nice solution for environments. What about for calling packages inside ```mypkg``` that are incompatible with ```beamer```, e.g. ```enumitem```? Or defining other commands.

Comment: You can set a boolean in \DeclareOption and then do something depending on its value later. But for testing the class it is easiest to do `\@ifclassloaded{beamer}{stuff only for beamer}{stuff not for beamer}`

Comment: Did the above comments help you solve your problem ?